# Executing multiple triggers

Tags: trigger

I currently have an `AfterUpdate` trigger on `Lead` and I need to add another action/logic - that isn't connected to the logic in the current trigger
(one handles the Lead source - while the other handles information on the company)

How do I call both classes?
Or - if both are fired `AfterUpdate` - how can I control their order?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They'll both fire "after update" in undetermined order which can lead to many interesting debugging sessions ;)

You should have at most 1 trigger inn each "triggering condition". There's a [best practice](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/04/apex-trigger-tip-using-a-class-per-object-to-control-logic.html) to have at most one trigger per object (not per condition on object; per whole object).

See http://www.embracingthecloud.com/2010/07/08/ASimpleTriggerTemplateForSalesforce.aspx for some inspiration.

*(copied the main part of the blog post here as it appears to be down at the moment)*

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after delete, after insert, after undelete,
    after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {
    AccountTriggerHandler handler = new AccountTriggerHandler(Trigger.isExecuting, Trigger.size);

    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore){
        handler.OnBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
    }
    else if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.OnAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
        AccountTriggerHandler.OnAfterInsertAsync(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
    }
    else if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore){
        handler.OnBeforeUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
    }
    else if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.OnAfterUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
        AccountTriggerHandler.OnAfterUpdateAsync(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
    }
    else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore){
        handler.OnBeforeDelete(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
    else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.OnAfterDelete(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
        AccountTriggerHandler.OnAfterDeleteAsync(Trigger.oldMap.keySet());
    }
    else if(Trigger.isUnDelete){
        handler.OnUndelete(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Comment: AWSOME link !!!

Comment: Kudos to my former boss, no idea where he dug it out from but I keep it in my favorites and try to advocate the use wherever I go.

Comment: Looks a "reddit effect" has occured, site is down? Google cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dMm19JD5J68J:www.embracingthecloud.com/2010/07/08/ASimpleTriggerTemplateForSalesforce.aspx+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Comment: I've also found this link and subsequent comments helpful in the past discussing the merits of different approaches: http://gokubi.com/archives/two-interesting-ways-to-architect-apex-triggers

Comment: Is it just me or does this seem like a lot of overkill?

Comment: @Ralph - I treat it as a guideline. I do like the idea of "lean" triggers and core of my code in helper class but I tend to make methods & properties of said class static, so no instantiating in the beginning. And I keep method names meanigful, so `rollupSummariesToAccount` and not `onAfterinsert`. But the idea to have 1 file with everything saved my bacon on couple occasions... If only we'd have control on order of execution of my & managed package's triggers...

Comment: Amen to that.  I started with trigger helper classes that had all the logic for one object, but they got really bloated quickly and the logic from one method to another didn't really fit together logically, except for the fact they're operating on the same object.  And managed packages are totally SOL on this front.

Comment: For those that want to add a dash of OO programming to their trigger handlers you might like this... http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Domain_Layer ;-) Worlds smallest trigger in just one line! SObjectDomain.triggerHandler(Opportunities.class); There is also some mocking support to be played with!

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest that the logic be moved out to a class or classes that can do the work.
You can then, from the trigger, call the logic that is appropriate in response to the event.
Here is a little pseudocode example:

```
//Add in the after and before events that you are interested in
trigger Lead_Trigger on Lead (after update) {

    if (Trigger.isAfter) {        
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            LeadSource.processUpdatedLeads(trigger.old, trigger.new);
            CompanyInfoHelper.processUpdatedLeads(trigger.old, trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to control the order in which triggers on the same event (and object) are fired.

The only way to do this is one trigger with all the logic. Or as I would recommend moving the heavy lifting into some helper classes for code clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any control of the order in which a trigger fires.  But you have complete control over how the code executes within the trigger.  For all my clients we use a one trigger per object per operation.  @eyescream's answer has the same goal, but I find that one trigger per object per operation is WAY easier on the brain and cuts down on the nested if statements.  Some other more complicated trigger handlers just end up recreating this same structure, but are added complexity with no benefit.

So for each object you can have up to eight triggers (although you'll only create the ones you need for the moment), then pull your logic into an external class so you don't end up with mile long triggers.  Hook in classes for the operations they need to be there on.

**Account_BeforeInsert**

```
trigger Account_BeforeInsert on Account (before insert) {

  // populate owner manager field for easy workflow emails
  Account_TriggerHelper.updateOwnerManager(trigger.new);

  // run custom account assignment (only do this on account creation)
  AccountAssigner roundRobin = new AccountAssigner(trigger.new);
  roundRobin.runAssignment();
}
```

**Account_AfterInsert**

```
trigger Account_AfterInsert on Account (after insert) {

  // update account ownership metircs (can't do this until after since
  // the data isn't queryable in before)
  AccountOwnershipMetrics metricUpdate = new AccountOwnershipMetrics(trigger.new);
  metricUpdate.doUpdate();

}
```

**Account_BeforeUpdate**

```
trigger Account_BeforeUpdate on Account (before update) {

  // check that owner manager is still up to date
  Account_TriggerHelper.updateOwnerManager(trigger.new);

}
```

**Account_AfterUpdate**

```
trigger Account_AfterUpdate on Account (after update) {

  // update account ownership metrics if the owner has changed
  AccountOwnershipMetrics metricUpdate = 
      new AccountOwnershipMetrics(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
  metricUpdate.doUpdate();

}
```

Comment: What if you need a "homemade rollup summary" recalculation? Say `after insert, after update, before delete, after undelete`? Do you end up putting same/similar method call in all 3 places? I'd prefer to keep it in 1 file for nice overview of all "magic that happens on save of this object". But I agree it makes code bit longer.

Comment: Yep, you need to put it in all four.  At the end of the day it seems to be purely philosophical, do you like shorter triggers, or one trigger with a lot of nested if statements.  IMHO multiple triggers is cleaner since you're generally only concerned with one operation when troubleshooting, but it's not exactly a compelling reason to choose one way or the other.